# How to declare a while loop which will work until successful completion of the fetch statement in PL/PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I have a procedure in PL/PGSQL where I have declared a cursor now when I tried to execute this loop
**while(parents%FOUND)** where **parents** is a cursor var it's showing error :

*org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: refcursor % boolean
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.*

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: See here [Cursor loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP).